# Javascript to alert a user that the same info has already been entered

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

First I should say I am a javascript newbie so forgive my ignorance.
I'm creating a form that has three functions and also uses array: 
Add - To accept a name (if field left blank it should ask the user to enter a name in an alert box)
Find - To verify a name has not already been entered (in an alert box)
List - To list the names that have been entered (in an alert box)

I have the list function working (good).  The alert to enter a name comes up after you enter a name as well as when you leave the field blank (not good)
and I can't get the find function to work at all.
My code is below and I've tried so many iterations and searched so many sites for help, also tried firebug; I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
    
    
    Untitled

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = new Array();

  function list() {
      var s = "";
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          s = s + a[i] + "\n";
      alert(s);
  }

  function add() {
      // If the text box empty you ask the user to enter a name.
      var myTextField = document.getElementById("myText");
      a[a.length] = myTextField.value;
      myTextField.value = "";
      if (myTextField.value == "") {
          alert("Please enter a name");
          return false;
      }

      function find() {
          //If the name already exists you should get a warning
          var myTextField = document.getElementById("myText");
          a[a.length] = myTextField.value;
          myTextField.value = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
              if (a[i] == myTextField) {
                  alert("Sorry, the name " + a[i] + " already exists.  Try again");
              }
      }
  }

</script>
<input type="text" id="myText" /><br>
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add a name" />
<input type="button" onclick="list()" value="List the names" />
<input type="button" onclick="find()" value="Find" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it almost, but some lil errors.. here you can check it [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAFse/5/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Add a name" class="add_button"/>
<input type="button" value="List the names" class="list_button"/>
<input type="button" value="Find" class="find_button"/>
```

JS:

```
$(".add_button").live("click", function(){
    add()
});

$(".list_button").live("click", function(){
    list()
});

$(".find_button").live("click", function(){
    find()
});


var a = new Array();
function list()
{
    var s = "";
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    s = s + a[i] + "\n";
    alert(s);
 }

function add()
{
   // If the text box empty you ask the user to enter a name.
    var myTextField = document.getElementById("myText");
    a[a.length] = myTextField.value;

    if (myTextField.value == "")
    {
        alert ("Please enter a name");
        return false;
    }
    myTextField.value = "";
}

function find()
{
    //If the name already exists you should get a warning
    var status = true;
    var myTextField = document.getElementById("myText");

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == myTextField.value)
        {
            alert ("Sorry, the name " + a[i] + " already exists.  Try again");
            status = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(status==true)
    {
        a[a.length] = myTextField.value;
    }
    myTextField.value = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you much, I see where I went wrong.  It now works perfectly!

Comment: np :) glad could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The code had a couple of errors, here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/sAq2m/2/

html:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" /><br>
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add a name" />
<input type="button" onclick="listItems()" value="List the names" />
<input type="button" onclick="find()" value="Find" />
```

js:

```
 var a = [];
  function listItems()
 {
  var s = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  s = s + a[i] + "\n";
  alert(s);
     return false;
 }

 function add()
{
   // If the text box empty you ask the user to enter a name.
 var myTextField = document.getElementById("myText");
    var v = myTextField.value
    if (!v){
        v = prompt("You have not entered a name, please enter one.");
    } 
    a.push(v);

    console.log(a);
  myTextField.value = "";      

 return false;
}
 function find()
{
 //If the name already exists you should get a warning
 var myTextField = document.getElementById("myText");

 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    if (a[i] == myTextField.value)
    { 
        alert ("Sorry, the name " + a[i] + " already exists.  Try again");
        return;
    }
}
```